# Transactions across remote EJB Calls

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, ejb

EDIT: I figured the first part of my question out myself - to avoid closing my question and opening a new one for the second part, i recycle this question and provide the link for accessing remote EJB ont he same applicationserver:
[github example, thanks to PiotrNowicki](https://github.com/PiotrNowicki/ear-intercommunication/blob/master/ear-intercommunication.client/ear-intercommunication.client.ejb/src/main/java/com/piotrnowicki/ejbintercommunication/client/Client.java)

I have a War and a ear.
The Ear contains a @Stateful EJB, using a PersistenceContext.EXTENDED for some databaseoperations. This Context is extended for access to Lazy-fetched lists in Entities outside the Persistence-bean.

The WAR has a JAX-RS REST-Interface, implemented using @Stateless Sessionbeans, which also do simple operations on other datasources. they do not require an extended context, so they use regular CMT.

the Beans in the WAR however need to call the EAR'S EJBs.

If I just Merge the Projects into one EAR and inject the beans via @EJB, the CMT cannot interact with the Extended Persistence-Context. This is expected, see JPA spec 7.6.3. (@Stateless beans attach a regular PersistenceContext to the transaction, which an extended context does not accept)

So I split the two Services and now need a Service-Interface for interaction.

My Question is:

1) Would remote EJB-calls SOLVE the Transaction-Problem, or would the JBOSS behave like the Bean was Local and try to add the Extended persistencecontext to the local transaction - resulting in the same problem?

Comment: Do you use your Extended Persistence Context on Stateful EJBs only or do you use it on ALL your EJB's (Stateless + Stateful EJBs)?

Comment: only statefull, stateless would not accept an extended ctx i think

Comment: I asked because you wrote about using Stateless EJB's.

Comment: I figured out part of it - the main question now is, are the Transactions spanned accross the applications, or does the remote EJB handle its transaction independently?

Comment: I realise this isn't quite the question you're asking, but are you sure you want to hold the transaction open for this?  You could just eagerly fetch the lists in your entities and end the transaction - this would mean loading more data, possibly redundantly, but I'd expect it to be more performant and scalable (in most cases) than holding long-running transactions open across several remote calls?